# How to disable auto configuration when test profile in @SpringBootApplication?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-profiles, spring-autoconfiguration

Are there elegant ways to prevent AutoConfigure configuration classes when certain profile (e.g. `test`) in use? I've all configs in my tests, and don't wanna mark every config in main folder with `@Profile("!test")`

there also is: `@SpringBootApplication(exclude=****Configuration.class)` possibility but it's for class, not for profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did (but not for test) its to disable the AutoConfigure via properties file when a certain profile is enabled.

For instance, I don't want Redis to be auto-configured when profile "withoutRedis" is enabled (dev purpose).
I created a property file "application-withoutRedis.properties" and its content :

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration
```